# Android : GreenDroid-GoogleAPIs fails with StackOverflow Exception during Import

Tags: android, import, stack-overflow, greendroid

I just tried to Import the GreenDroid-Librarys for my new Android Application.

Now, I encounter a confusing Error. I first Import the GreenDroid-Core Library and everything is fine.

But when I, after that, try to Import the GreenDroid-GoogleAPI Library into my workspace I get a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

The detailed Error is as followed:

```
Failed to call IProjectListener.projectOpened
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I´m not sure if this is a problem with my Eclipse or with the Library per se.

Comment: What solution have you figured